# How to get initial step function input request in event bridge which after multiple steps

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have below step function and if lambda return other than statuscode 200 then I need to retry again by sending the input request. But I am unable to get the whatever input request send to Parallel state same I need to send back to event bus. How to get the initial input request in event bridge step?

[image]